# Why does a VS2010 installation start when I start VB6?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb6, ide, windows-10

I just upgraded to Windows 10 and noticed that some programs, such as Visual Studio 2010, start a setup when I try to run them and look for their install files. What really makes me wonder though is that this VS2010 setup also starts when I run the VB6 IDE. How can these two be connected?

(I also have VS2008 and VS2013 installed and they don't have these issues.)

Answer (score 1):

Felix,

When I went through this situation, the only way to resolve it was reinstalling VS2010. In my case when I so was using Windows 7

I tried to restore the system, use CCleaner and others, but none succeeded.

Please try reinstalling VS2010! I hope this helps!

Comment: For me the issue disappeared mysteriously after about one month of daily use. I have no clue what did this, maybe CCleaner.